# Sharepoint Calendar Overlay not finding lists from sharepoint URL

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-office

I have a sharepoint site with multiple Lists.  I created and saved calendar views based on these lists, and the individual views are working fine.

Afterwards I go to the Calendar page -> Calendars Overlay -> New Calendar.  Type of Calendar: SharePoint.  My site URL is pre-populated, I click Resolve, and the only list that shows up is the pre-made "Tasks" list.

I would like to add these Calendar views to a Calendar Overlay to display on the SharePoint site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Resolve button to populate the List drop-down with available Calendars from this site and select the desired calendar.

[image]

Alternatively, you can overlay another SharePoint calendar as long as both SharePoint calendars are in the same site collection. In all, you can add up to four SharePoint calendars.

For more details, please refer to the link: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/01/create-calendar-overlay-in-sharepoint-online.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [modern experience calendar views in custom list](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/) in SharePoint online, it is not possible to add these modern calendar views in calendar overlays.

You will need to create lists with classic experience "Calendar" list template to add calendars in calendar overlays.

**Related Read**: [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)